# Simple Javascript code needed? (.js file)

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a .js file that has multiple **submit buttons** lined up vertically on a page. If you click the 1st one, it will direct you to a page (or stay on the current page but wipe everything clean) that contains a paragraph of text that basically tells you that you clicked the **first button**. If you click the **second button**, then it will display a paragraph saying you've clicked the second, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all these buttons the same class, then try something like this:

```
var addresses  = ["url.htm", "url2.htm"];

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    (function(iVal) {
        buttons[iVal].onclick = function() {
           location.href = addresses[iVal]
        };
     })(i);
```

Of course this assumes the buttons will be returned from `getElementsByClasName` in the same order they exist on the page.  I think that's true, but I'm not certain.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without directing the user to additional files (at least not html files)...?

Comment: @JacobGriffin - I thought the point was that the user clicks on a button, and is redirected?  `location.href = foo.htm` redirects the user to foo.htm.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer when the system lets me to. I'll also post up a similar question as well that kind of clarifies what I'm talking about. Gracias!